# Error al ejecutar Reporte Jasper en Java/Swing

Tags: java, java-swing, jasper-reports, librería, jasper

tengo un problema al intentar ejecutar un informe de JasperSoft. El código que ejecuta el informe es el siguiente:

```
atos = PostgreSQL.getInstancia();
    conn = datos.getConeccionOn();
    JasperReport informe;
    String rutaInforme = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/reports/ListaCompras.jrxml";
    try {
        informe = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(rutaInforme);
        JasperPrint impresora = JasperFillManager.fillReport(rutaInforme, null, conn);
        JasperViewer visor = new JasperViewer(impresora, false);
        visor.setDefaultCloseOperation(JasperViewer.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        visor.setVisible(true);
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ApplicationEVT.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        datos.setConeccionOff();
    }
```

La excepción que obtengo es la siguiente:

```
erreports.engine.JRException.getMessage(JRException.java:148)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException.getMessage(JRException.java:139)
at java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:391)
at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:480)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2982)
at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:754)
..........
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 68 more
```

Aclaro que ***no*** estoy utilizando Spring en la aplicación. Es una aplicación JAVA desktop (Swing) con las siguientes librerias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy empezando a programar y no tengo muy claro que esta sucediendo. Desde ya gracias por su atención y saludos a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Comprobá si contás con [las dependencias](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.11.0) que corresponden a esa versión de la librería de jasperreports (en este caso, 6.11.0). El problema se suele producir cuando las dependencias son incompatibles con la versión con la que disponés en tu proyecto.

En este caso, ellas son:

- commons-beanutils (1.9.4)
- commons-digester (2.1)
- commons-logging (1.1.1)
- commons-collections4 (4.2)
- itext (2.1.7.js7)
- jcommon (1.0.23)
- jfreechart (1.0.19)
- ecj (4.4.2)
- castor-xml (1.4.1)
- jackson-core (2.10.0)
- jackson-databind (2.10.0)
- jackson-annotations (2.10.0)

Comment: Mil gracias. Pruebo y te cuento. Desde ya eternamente agradecido. Saludos cordiales.